# Redirect bounced mails, and read the attached filename from the bounced mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have 2 programs one to send mail and another to read mails. My 1st question is how can I redirect the bounced mails to an email id other than the user. 2nd questions is if I have a bounced mail how do I read the name of the file attached. I have gone through many of the posting but nothing seems to be working. Any help is appreciated.

Code used to send mail

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class bounceMail {
    String host, port, emailid,username, password;
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    Session l_session = null;
    Session l_session1= null;

    public void sendMessage(String toEmail, String subject, String msg) {
        host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        port = "465";

        emailid = "fromemailid";
        username = "fromusername";
        password = "******";

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        //props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.from", "bounceemailid"); // not working
        l_session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
        //l_session.setDebug(true); // Enable the debug mode

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(l_session);

            //message.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse("bounceemail@yahoo.com")); // not working
            //message.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("bounceemail@yahoo.com")); // not working
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(msg, "text/html");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Message Sent");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static public void main(String args[]){
        bounceMail b = new bounceMail();
        b.sendMessage("junkemailid","Test","test Mail");
    }

}
```

Code used to read the mail

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;



public class CheckingMail {

  public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
  String password) 
  {
    try {

    //create properties field
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.imap.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
    properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
    Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);


    Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(host, user, password);

    //create the folder object and open it
    Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
    Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false)); 
    System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
    int bcnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
       Message message = messages[i];
       if(message.getFrom()[0].toString().contains("MAILER-DAEMON")){
         bcnt++;
       }
       System.out.println("---------------------------------");
       System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
       System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
       System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);

       Object content = message.getContent();
       if (content instanceof String)
           System.out.println("String");        

       if (content instanceof Multipart) {
           Multipart multipart = (Multipart) content;
           for (int j = 0; j < multipart.getCount(); j++) {
              System.out.println(multipart.getBodyPart(j).getFileName());
           }
       }

       for(int j=0;j<message.getAllRecipients().length; j++){
           System.out.println("Recipients "+j+" : " + message.getAllRecipients()[j]);
       }
       System.out.println("Date: " + message.getSentDate());
    }
    System.out.println("Bounce count : " + bcnt);

    //close the store and folder objects
    emailFolder.close(false);
    store.close();

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     String host = "imap.mail.yahoo.com";
     String mailStoreType = "imap";
     String username = "emailid";
     String password = "*****";
     check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

  }

}
```

Is there a possibility to set own header or property when sending the mail which can be read when the mail bounces?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#bounce)?

You can set the SMTP "envelope From" address that's used to return failure messages by setting the "mail.smtp.from" property as described in the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.smtp package](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html).

Comment: I have tried that, I get the following error when i use it @ Transport.send
`com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html;
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at bounceMail.sendMessage(bounceMail.java:49)`

Comment: Have you [verified the other email address in Yahoo Mail](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/steps-add-verify-email-accounts-yahoo-mail-sln22048.html)?

Comment: I want the code to work with all the mail provider not just Yahoo. I didn't understand what you meant by "verified the other mail address". The link takes me to add account, If you meant the same then i tried it, It still doesn't work.

Comment: In general, email providers are going to limit what email addresses you can use for "from" addresses, to prevent you from "spoofing" the source of your messages.  Some email providers have a way for you to prove that you own an email address, and then use that address as a "From" address in messages you send.  How that is done differs from provider to provider.  If you already did that for Yahoo Mail, and it still won't let you use that address as an "envelope From" address, you're probably out of luck.  You'll need to contact Yahoo Mail support to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the 2nd question. I was able to read the name of the attachment from the bounced mail with the below approach (need a better way to do it)

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(message.getContent().toString()));
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
    index = str.indexOf("filename");
    if(index >-1){
        filename = str.substring(index+9); // 9 characters -> "filename=" 
        if (filename.length() > 0) System.out.println("Attachment  : " + filename);
    }
}
```